# Javascript can't get value if input field connected to database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript can't get input field if it's connected to database? if typed manually it's work. any trick for that?

Here's my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#show').load('data.php')
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var money = 7000;

        $("#show").on("change keyup", function() {
            var input = $(this);

            // show message
            if( input.val() > money )
                $('#click').trigger('click');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea type="text" id="show" value=""></textarea>

    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello');" id="click">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

if value > my variable, then send trigger click. if typed manually it's work bro. any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click in the `.load(url, [callback])` optional callback function:

Few other changes, you don't have to maintain two different doc ready blocks one is enough to do the work, So you can combine them as:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var money = 7000;
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#show').load('data.php', function() {
        if ($("#show").val() > money) {
          $('#click').trigger('click');
        }
      });
    }, 2000);

    $("#show").on("change keyup", function() {
      var input = $(this);
      // show message
      if (input.val() > money)
        $('#click').trigger('click');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: one problem again bro, can you help me?

Comment: If that is short then ask here although better to ask a new question again. that would be much helpful for you.

Comment: if i click ok and data in database has not been converted into smaller data is alert will continue to appear. I know because I use setInterval. there is a solution to it in order not to repeat?

Comment: I can not make ask inquiries before 90 minutes dude

Comment: for this you can use a named interval and clear it with `clearInterval()` method when you need to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117993/discussion-between-eightleven-and-jai).

Comment: chat is disabled here at off. netw. environment. can't get on chat board

Comment: ahh, if used clearinterval so i can't get live data from database?

Comment: So, why you are using interval instead of setTimeout?

Comment: whether it's same if using setTimeout then use clearinterval?

Comment: No, `setInterval` can be used with `clearInterval` and `setTimeout` with `clearTimeout` but the `setInterval/setTimeout` have to be named ones.

Comment: yahh i mean it. so imposibble if  I made as I said ?

Comment: _there is a solution to it in order not to repeat?_ better to change it to `setTimeout` then.

Comment: can you write example? i really new in javascript

Comment: I mean change the term `setInterval` to `setTimeout` in then code so it will only run once.

Comment: yap nice you right it's work. but when i updated my data in database, it's not showing that is i must refresh page to get last data, I want the latest data continue to appear without refresh. and alert doesn't appear when I enter the new data because it uses a timeout occurs only once